# Failed exec.Command with fileName contain two spaces

Tags: windows, go, explorer

I want to open the file contain two spaces with explorer from Go's `exec.Command()`.

This command works as expected from Windows PowerShell.

```
Explorer "file://C:\Users\1. Sample\2.  Sample２"
```

And Using Go's `exec.Command()` works with fileName contain space like this.

```
exec.Command(`explorer`, "file://C:\Users\1. Sample").CombinedOutput()
```

But failed with fileName contain two spaces like this

```
exec.Command(`explorer`, "file://C:\Users\1. Sample\2.  Sample２").CombinedOutput()
```

Please tell me how to solve this.

---

This code works as expected. Thanks.

```
exec.Command(`explorer`, `file://C:\Users\1. Sample\2.  Sample２`).CombinedOutput()
```

But actual input is string(not raw string literal) as below. So I think that I need to convert string to raw string.

```
url := "file://C:\Users\1. Sample\2.  Sample２"

       <I need to convert to raw string literal?> 

result, err := exec.Command(`explorer`, url).CombinedOutput()

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Having 2 spaces in file names has nothing to do with failing to run the command.

You are using [interpreted string literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#interpreted_string_lit):

```
"file://C:\Users\1. Sample\2.  Sample２"
```

In interpreted string literals the backslash character `\` is special and if you want your `string` to have a backslash, you have to escape it, and the escape sequence is 2 backslahses: `\\`:

```
"file://C:\\Users\\1. Sample\\2.  Sample２"
```

Or even better: use [raw string literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#raw_string_lit) (and then you don't need to escape it):

```
`file://C:\Users\1. Sample\2.  Sample２`
```

That weird `２` character in your file name may also cause an issue. If you include that in Go source code, it will be interpreted and encoded as UTF-8 string. You pass this as a parameter, but your OS (windows) may use a different character encoding when checking file names, so it may not find it. Remove that weird `２` character from the file name if correcting the string literal is not sufficient to make it work.

When you run the command from PowerShell, it works because PowerShell does not expect an interpreted string and it uses the encoding that is also used to store file names.

Also [`Cmd.CombinedOutput()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.CombinedOutput) (just like [`Cmd.Run()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Run) and [`Cmd.Start()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Start)) returns an `error`, be sure to check that as it may provide additional info.

Comment: Shouldn't go translate encoding correctly when making windows syscalls?

Comment: Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @gaku Yes, use a raw string literal and remove weird characters from the file name. These are mentioned in the answer.

Comment: hmm.. exec.Command(`explorer`, "file://C:\Users\1. Sample\2. Sample") works but exec.Command(`explorer`, "file://C:\Users\1. Sample\2.  Sample")  doesn't works.  string literal can't convert to raw string literal?